# Finding optimal row reduction moves in C++

Tags: c++

For this problem, the time complexity does not matter. I have already constructed a function that can perform row operations on a matrix. I tried doing it the "bash" way:

```
void recursionfordataset(int range, std::vector<std::vector<int>> Dummy) {
  if (counter != 0) {
    for (int x = -range; x <= range; x++) {
      for (int y = -range; y <= range; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
              Dummy = add(Dummy[i], Dummy[j], Dummy, i, x, y);
              std::vector<int> move = {x, y};
              Moves.push_back(move);
              counter -= 1;
              recursionfordataset(range, Dummy);
              if (x!=0 && y!=0){
              Dummy = add(Dummy[i],Dummy[j], Dummy, i, 1/x, 1/y);
              }
              recursionfordataset(range, Dummy);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    bool yesno = TestIfIdentity(Dummy);
    if (yesno == true) {
      return;
    } else {
      Moves.clear();
      counter = 9;
      recursionfordataset(range, Dummy);
    }
  }
}
```

This essentially goes through all possible combinations of row operations within a certain range. The add function takes parameters (first row, second row, index of first row, constant1, constant2), where the change happens to the first row, and it is constant1 x first row+constant2 x second row.

I am running this code on locally, and it keeps crashing. I do not know of an alternative way that will get the precise moves. I confirmed with a research paper that it will take 9 moves for the 2x2 matrix Dummy to get reduced to the identity matrix.

I am thinking of using a different method, does anyone know of a way to do this without the "bash"?
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what this code is supposed to do? *Row reduction moves* is not clear for me...

Comment: `1/x` and `1/y` will be zero most of the time. They'll result in a divide-by-zero error as well.

Comment: Sorry about the divide by zero error, just fixed. It still crashes. @Damien, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination.

Comment: The code is complicated, also for people who know what Gaussian elimination is. Adding some comments could help make it less cryptic.